# Finding the Y axis value on a exponential trendline (MS Office Excel)

Tags: graphing-functions, exponential-function

Hello I'm having some problems finding out the correct equation, or if there is one, to find the value on the Y axis.
I have the following values:

```
4.33    22
3.7     33
3.63    35
3.55    38
3.31    48
3.28    49
3.23    52
3.14    55
2.98    62
2.92    64
2.75    71
```

I've made a scatter graph with an exponential trend line which looks a little like this:
[image]

Now if I wanted to find what the Y axis value is for example X axis value of 40, what would I do?
I'd like to also mention that the numbers on left side (y axis), are log from other numbers, I did these manually.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently for $x=40$ you have
$$y = 4.1499 e^{-0.037x}\approx 0.945$$
Admittedly, this doesn't match your raw data at all, so something must be wrong with the formula displayed.
On the other hand, you didn't plot the $x$ values to any scale, so marvels can happen.

Comment: I've changed the graph, i had made a mistake when I made it.

Answer (score 0):

For the record on this ancient question.

On occasion I've seen Excel seem to provide a similar wrong answer. The cause was too few decimal places in the exponent in the displayed regression equation. You can ask Excel to show you more. Try that. It may work here.